# Get current day Caldroid calendar

Tags: java, android

How to get current day on day click using Caldroid calendar in application in String format like "dddd mm yy"

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with a CaldroidListener and to get the date on select

```
public String currentDate;

final CaldroidListener listener = new CaldroidListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
             currentDate = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd", date);
        }
   ...
}
```

Comment: do you know how to hide or something like this CaldroidFragment?

Comment: maybe to set it's visibility to gone?

Comment: For example if it is in a RelativeLayout or something like this, you can get this element (the RalitiveLayout for example) by id and use the method setVisibility(View.GONE) over it

Comment: give the example please

Comment: For example if you have a RelativeLayout with a CaldroidFragment in it, which has an id `myLayout`, you could get it by id with `RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);` and after your program logic set the visibility to gone like this `mylayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: If it is not the case by you (I mean with a layout over the CaldroidFragment), please make me clearer in what kind of View is your CaldroidFragment positioned

Comment: here is my layout for Calroid:


    <LinearLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/calendar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

Comment: So I think you could hide it when you hide the LinearLayout. Try with
`LinearLayout calendar = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.calendar1);
 ...
calendar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: no problem, hopefully it's what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                String y = c.get(Calendar.SECOND)+";
                                String m = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+";
                                String d = c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+";
                                String = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+";
                                String q = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+";
                                String r = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `Calendar.getInstance()` to get current date and `SimpleDateFormat` to convert it to desired format like this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd mm yy");
String strDate = sdate.format(c.getTime());
```